# Structure formatting in C++

Tags: c++, structure

```
struct list* list_cons(int data_item, struct list* tail);
```

What does "list*" mean when I declare this structure, and for structures I thought I use curly brackets instead of brackets? Sorry for this question, I tried googling it but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: `list_cons` is a function, `struct list*` is the return type, a pointer to your struct.

Comment: are you sure this is C++ and not C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like code inherited from good old C where you have to state that the type you're using is a struct, unless it's explicitly typedef'd.

The `struct list*` at the start is the type returned by the function `list_cons`. In C++ you would simply write `list* list_cons`. Either syntax here means the function returns a pointer to a list structure.

Same goes for the parameters in the function, the first parameter is simply an int, the second parameter is a pointer to a list structure. Considering that the variable is named tail, I would expect it should be the back of the list.

If you've not covered pointers in C++ then you'll have to go a take a good long look into that first before understanding this.
Otherwise the `struct list*` in C is equivalent of `list*` in C++.

Answer (score 2):

This is a function declaration for the function `list_const` that accepts two parameter, an integer `data_item` and a pointer named `tail` that points to an object of type `list`. The return value of that function is again a pointer to an object of type `list`. You could also rewrite this snippet to

```
struct list; // forward-declare the type

list* list_cons(int data_item, list* tail);  // declare function without 'struct' keyword
```

Comment: oh I understand now thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Function can be declared as:

```
return_type func_name(arg1, arg2)

struct list* list_cons(int data_item, struct list* tail);

> return_type ---> struct list*
func_name ----> list_cons
arg1 -----> int data_item
arg2 ---------> struct list* tail
```

So basically, `struct list* list_cons(int data_item, struct list* tail);` is a function declaration which takes two arguments as **data_item** and  **pointer to tail**. It **returns a pointer of struct list** type.

Answer (score 0):

You are **MERGING** the declaration of a list structure and the declaration of a  pointer that points to a list.This function is taking two arguments of type int and a pointer to type list.So It is **not needed** for every structure to be declared like this.